# Neo4j Query is not returning anything whereas in browser same query works fine

Tags: node.js, database, neo4j

Here is the code...

```
var query = 'MATCH ( A:user { user_id:"user1"}) RETURN A';
var callback=function (err, res) {
    if (err){
       console.log(err);
    }
    else {
       console.log("Sign in response:"+res);
       console.log("Sign in response:"+res.columns);
    } 
};

var query_runner=require('./run_query2')
query_runner.run_query2(query,callback);
```

and The run_query method is defined as...

```
var run_query2=function(query,callback){
    var neo4j = require('node-neo4j');
    db = new neo4j('http://username:password@localhost:7474');
    db.cypherQuery(query,callback);
}
module.exports.run_query2=run_query2;
```

NOTE:Creating a new entry works fine.
And the MATCH query worked fine when I tried it in the browser.
But when I try doing the same with the code, nothing gets returned.
stuck here for 3-4 hours.
HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks at least in v2 that you have to provide a  `{query: "", params: {} }` object to the query function, see:

https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j/tree/v2#cypher

```
db.cypher({
    query: 'MATCH (user:User {email: {email}}) RETURN user',
    params: {
        email: 'alice@example.com',
    },
}, callback);
```

Answer (score 1):

Coding looks good. Similar happened to me and solved by changing the quotation. Can you try by changing the "" (quotation) sth like `"MATCH ( A:user { user_id:'user1'}) RETURN A"`